# Passing a string to navigation.navigate

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation

I'm trying to set a menu and I'm trying to pass the path to navigation.navigate as navigation.navigate(menu.path) but it doesn't allow me to pass the route in that way.

So I create the item here with the path as selections.name

```
    export default function Menu_1({ navigation }) {
      const [selections, setSelections] = useState([
        { title: 'Normas de utilización de la App', key:'1' , name:'Normas'},
        { title: 'Zonas maritimas', key:'2'}
      ])
```

When I try to pass that path to navigation.navigate it doesn't allow to me unless I use Navigation.navigate('Normas')

```
     return (
            <View style={globalStyles.container}>
              <FlatList
                data={selections}
                renderItem={({ item })=>(
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate()}>
                    <Card>
                      <Image
                      style={{ 
                        width: 100, 
                        height: 50,
                      }} 
                      source={images.images_menu[item.key]} />
                      <Text style={globalStyles.titleCard}> {item.title} </Text>
                    </Card>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                  
                )}
              />
            </View>     
        )   
    }
```

is there a way to pass the string from selections.name to navigation.navigate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood this correctly, you can access the `selections.name` in the `item` param of your `renderItem` prop, like this:

```
 return (
        <View style={globalStyles.container}>
          <FlatList
            data={selections}
            renderItem={({ item })=>(
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate(item.name)}> // item.name
                <Card>
                  <Image
                  style={{ 
                    width: 100, 
                    height: 50,
                  }} 
                  source={images.images_menu[item.key]} />
                  <Text style={globalStyles.titleCard}> {item.title} </Text>
                </Card>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              
            )}
          />
        </View>     
    )
```

You can also switch this to whatever you want, `navigate(item.key)`, `navigate(item.foo)`. Just make sure you are keeping the values here

```
const [selections, setSelections] = useState([
        { title: 'Normas de utilización de la App', key:'1' , name:'Normas'},
        { title: 'Zonas maritimas', key:'2', name: 'Foo'} // missing name
      ])
```